# How to clone the element in YUI3?

Tags: yui

I have div element and inside that few more element like UL , span etc.

So, how can i clone the element like jquery clone.

Please don't suggest http://www.jsrosettastone.com/ because i already checked there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
YUI().use('node', function(Y){
   var node = Y.one('#doc');
   var clone = node.cloneNode(true); // true tells it to do a deep clone
});
```

It's in the YUI API docs:
http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/api/classes/Node.html#method_cloneNode